# How can I use grep with pipe?

Tags: unix

How can I use grep with pipe?

For example, I want to find all files in the directory which contain strings : s1="aaa" and s2="bbb"

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
grep -rl "aaa" dir | grep "bbb"
```

Comment: Some time with the grep documentation might be in order; a pipe isn’t necessary. That said: “it doesn’t work” it’s not diagnostic. Be specific.

Comment: The reason your pipe doesn’t work, btw, is because your second grep is grepping the output of the first grep, not grepping the files over again.

Comment: If you solved your problem, post it as an answer, not an edit to the question